# Detox + Circle CI

Tags: circleci, detox

It would be great if I can have a way to run detox on CircleCI. I saw some of the post about running on Travis but because I am new to CI stuffs. So I am still not sure what would be a good way to set up and run the test on CircleCI.

Comment: What exactly is stopping you from running detox on Circle CI? If it allows you running shell scripts and simulators (like Travis CI does), it should theoretically work.